# How to test that method should raise different types of exceptions?

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec

I have the following method:

```
  def call_http_service(url, url_params)
    begin
      conn = create_connection(url)
      resp = get_response(conn, url_params)
      raise_if_http_status_error(resp)
      xml_resp = parse_xml(resp)
      raise_if_client_status_error(xml_resp)

      return xml_resp
    rescue ClientError => e
      raise ClientError, "Error interacting with feed at #{url}: #{e.message}"
    rescue Faraday::Error::ClientError => e
      raise ClientError, "Error interacting with feed at #{url}: #{e.message}"
    rescue Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError => e
      raise ClientParseError, "Error parsing response from #{url}: #{e.message}"
    rescue => e
      raise e
    end
  end
```

Based on my limited understanding of RSpec, it looks like the way to test that these different types of Exceptions are raised is to use [message expectations](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-8/docs/message-expectations).  Is that how you would approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
it "raises ClientError when the HTTP request raises ClientError"
  # stub the http request here to raise the error
  expect do
    subject.call_http_service 'http://example.com'
  end.to raise_error(ClientError)
end
```

Note: Rescuing and reraising a different error is code smell.